# Android http URL scheme is not working when I try to launch my application from a link on my website

Tags: android, url

I'm trying to achieve to have my application launched (or fire an open-in dialog) when a link pointing to http://example.com/123 on my website is clicked.
In my AndroidManifest.xml I added the following activity to register my app for 'http' links with host 'example.com'. But it simply visits http://example.com/123 link and nothing happens other than that when I touch on the link.

```
<activity xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:name=".TestActivity"
          android:label="myapplication">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also tried with

```
android:pathPattern = ".*"
```

or

```
android:pathPattern = "*"
```

but none of them work. I appreciate for any suggestions from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pathPrefix instead of pathPattern.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data 
        android:host="example.com"
        android:scheme="http"
        android:pathPrefix="/"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Although I'm still having trouble with top-level domains other than com and net, pathPrefix solved my issue with com TLD. Thanks for the suggestion :)